# Arrays - how to dynamically dereference array? (Perl)

Tags: arrays, perl

When I do:

```
my (@array1, @array2) = get_returns();
```

The `get_return` function returns a list of arbitrary elements.
In this particular case, the `get_returns` function returns a list of two arrays. However this stores all the contents of the return into `array1` instead of splitting the two arrays up.

I am not sure how to dereference the arrays through the function I am calling using something explicit like `@{$arr}`. I am doing a form of RPC calling where the returns (and their types) are not known beforehand by the program. I also do not want to have to dereference the array outside of the function call. **Is there a workaround to dynamically dereference the arrays?**

**Update**

In the `get_returns` function, I am sending and receiving a response from a server. This returns a JSON table where the "returns" field is an array of returns:

```
sub get_returns {
    my $data = remotely_call_some_function();
    $t = $json->decode($data);
    my @returns = @{$t->{"returns"}};
    return @returns;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code in the `get_returns()` function.

Comment: @stevieb, I have updated the question

Comment: Ok, so that's a single list that's being returned. What does: `use Data::Dumper; my @ret = get_returns(); print Dumper \@ret;` show?

Comment: @stevieb: $VAR1 = [['e1', 'e2'], ['e1', 'e2']];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *the get_returns function returns a list of two arrays.*

No, it returns a number of scalars. That's the only thing a sub can return. In this specific case, it returns two references to arrays. You could grab them as follows:

```
my ($array1, $array2) = get_returns();
```

---

> I also do not want to have to dereference the array outside of the function

To do that, you'd need named arrays outside of `get_returns` for `get_returns` to populate.

```
sub get_returns {
    my $data_json = remotely_call_some_function();
    my $data = $json->decode($data_json);
    my $returns = $data->{returns};
    @{ $_[0] } = $returns->[0];
    @{ $_[1] } = $returns->[1];
}

get_returns(\my @array1, \my @array2);
```

I recommend against this.

Comment: This solution definitely works. I was mainly hoping that the users do not have to change the way they call the function. Is it normal for Perl users to do something like my($array1, $array2) = get_returns() instead of my(@array1, @array2) = get_returns?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "with array returns", but `my($array1, $array2) = get_returns()` is very common.

Comment: @d33 Those are *array references* being returned, not arrays, and what ikegami has shown is exceptionally common. You could also do it like this: `my @a = get_returns();` which would put aref1 into `$a[0]` and aref2 into `$a[1]`. Then you could deref like this `$a[0]->[0]` or `for (@{ $a[0] }){...}`. Whatever makes the code more understandable is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Per a comment that includes `Data::Dumper` output in the OP, you're receiving `$VAR1 = [['e1', 'e2'], ['e1', 'e2']]`. That's an array of array references. Here's how you can receive and then dereference the inner arefs:

```
my ($aref1, $aref2) = get_returns();

# deref and print each element of an array reference

for my $elem (@$aref1){
    print "$elem\n";
}

# get a single element

my $x = $aref2->[0];
```